# I have a table which contains data with a date column. Mysql Query help needed!

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select, date

Now, I am using php timestamp (time()) in my columns as a timestamp. I use it because I thought that storing it as integer would be efficient than using datetime.

Now I am having serious problems with selecting time between two timestamps.

For example, I am trying to get records added yesterday (that is between today's date in php timestamp and todaysdate - 24 hours in php timestamp)

It looks like this in sql pseudo code

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date < phptimestamp(todaysdate) AND date > phptimestamp(todaysdate -24h)
```

It does get me some records but for some reason the records between this range keep on chaning. The timestamps that I am looking between are static. The records between those time stamps should not be changing because all the records that are added have a currtime stamp.

Real Code

```
$date = getdate();

$m = time() - (5 * 60);
$h = time() - (($date['minutes'] * 60) + $date['seconds']);
$d = time() - ((60 * 60 * $date['hours']) + ($date['minutes'] * 60) + $date['seconds']);
$y = time() - ((60 * 60 * 24) + ($date['hours'] * 60 * 60) + ($date['minutes'] * 60) + $date['seconds']);

$crawledm = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(crawled) as count FROM domains WHERE crawled != '' AND crawled > '{$m}'"));
$crawledm = $crawledm['count'];
$crawledh = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(crawled) as count FROM domains WHERE crawled != '' AND crawled > '{$h}'"));
$crawledh = $crawledh['count'];
$crawledd = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(crawled) as count FROM domains WHERE crawled != '' AND crawled > '{$d}'"));
$crawledd = $crawledd['count'];
$crawledy = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(crawled) as count FROM domains WHERE crawled != '' AND crawled > '{$y}' AND crawled < '{$d}'"));
$crawledy = $crawledy['count'];
```

Comment: Need more code to fully analyse (PHP calling this mysql, etc...) ... real code is 10x better than pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are using the [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html) column type in your table, and not a UNIX timestamp (which would just be an integer).

There is no reason to store datetimes as an integer - MySQL (and every other dbms) is optimized to handle dates and times in a very intelligent manner.

Assuming you are storing your dates in datetime/timestamp columns, you should be able to use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Also, as you work with dates and times in MySQL, [this doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) is your friend.

Comment: I would suggest changing that, personally.  Otherwise, you can enclose every reference to your unix timestamp columns in FROM_UNIXTIME, as alexn suggested.

Comment: Could you possible give me query please. I understand that it may be to much to ask, so you dont have to.

Comment: You should be able to just replace the table/column names in my example with your table's names.  To give you the exact query, I would need to know the structure of your table (you still haven't specified the data type of your timestamp column, which I'm guessing is "crawled").  Based on your updated post, I'm assuming it is an integer storing unix timestamps?  If so, I would suggest changing its datatype, as per my answer up there.

Comment: -->>table ->domains -->>Columns ->domain (varchar), crawled (int)

Answer (score 0):

Replace phptimestamp with [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert your integer to a actual timestamp. This should enable you to compare actual dates and not just integers.

Comment: I am using phptimestamp in the table, and that is the problem